# How to add an observer in Objective-C and fire a Notification in Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsnotificationcenter, notificationcenter

I have a notification observer in an Objective C file and I want to fire a notification in a Swift 3 file. Since in Objective C the notification name is a NSString but in Swift 3 it's Notification.Name, how can I get the Obj-C observer to catch the Swift fire?

Swift Trigger

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .notificationName, object: nil, userInfo: nil)

extension Notification.Name {
    static let notificationName = Notification.Name("Test")
}
```

Obj-C Observer

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(displayError:)
                                      name:"Test"
                                      object:nil];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would trigger the notification like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(
    name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "SomeNotification"),
    object: nil,
    userInfo: nil
)
```

Comment: The observer is in an Objective C file though

Comment: Should work :)... Just disregard the listening part of my answer.

Comment: NSNotification does not have a Name property in Objective C. I have no problem with the trigger. I just can't get the observer to catch it

Comment: Can you show the code you have?
I believe it should work since (from docs) `typealias Notification.Name = NSNotification.Name` and `In Objective-C, NSNotification names are type aliased to the NSString class.`

Comment: That should work :)...  Are you sure that the observer is added before the notification is sent?

Comment: yep. I checked the list of observers at the time the trigger in swift is set off and the observer is in the list. Everything is saying this should work but obviously I'm missing something!

Comment: Can you try in objc observer to add the name "TestNotification"?

Comment: @JanKaltoun got it working. The problem was me being silly. Anyways now I'm getting an error saying that the UIViewAlertController has invalid layout constraints even though I'm not customizing it at all. Any ideas?

Comment: @Schuey999 I'm glad it works :). Please accept this answer, create a new question with this new issue and code that's failing and send me the link to it.

Comment: @JanKaltoun https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425217/basic-uialertcontroller-unable-to-satisfy-constraints