# Basic UIAlertController Unable to satisfy constraints

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, uialertcontroller

```
 UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                                                         message:message
                                                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alertController show];
```

This code is causing the following error:

```
...[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7af32260 h=-&- v=-&- UITransitionView:0x7ae60c70.height == UIWindow:0x7aebc600.height   (active)>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7af9b6f0 h=--- v=--- UIWindow:0x7aebc600.height == 0   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79f1f050 UIView:0x7ae6ec40.height >= 44   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79f1d6a0 _UIAlertControllerView:0x7a26ce00'Error'.height == UIView:0x7ae6ec40.height   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7aafb360 _UIAlertControllerView:0x7a26ce00'Error'.centerY == UITransitionView:0x7ae60c70.centerY   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7afb81e0 V:|-(>=0)-[_UIAlertControllerView:0x7a26ce00'Error']   (active, names: '|':UITransitionView:0x7ae60c70 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79f1f050 UIView:0x7ae6ec40.height >= 44   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to     catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView  listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Note: In the wider context of what my app is doing, I have no choice but to use `[alertController show]`

Comment: a `UIAlertController` instance's *layout* shouldn't be managed by you... you just present it and the rest is taken care of by UIKit way of handling AlertControllers. I'm guessing your adding a constraint where you shouldn't add *any*.

Comment: I'm not adding anything. The code snippet above is literally all I'm doing

Comment: googling "Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint" I was able to find many questions on stackoverflow including: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107762/autolayout-constraints-warning-will-attempt-to-recover-by-breaking-constraint). Take a look

Comment: but I'm not modifying/adding/removing any of constraints. I'm just creating an alert controller and trying to show it

Comment: well apparently you're doing something wrong. try googling that error and you might find something...I'm also trying to demystify it...

Comment: I've used `UIAlertController` quite often and have never seen this happen. Please add the code around what you are showing. There must be something wrong with what you are not showing here.

Comment: or perhaps it's something you're doing in storyboard...

Comment: or perhaps it is happening only in a particular iOS version? Are you debugging on device or emulator. What iOS version ...

Comment: Two questions: are you using some kind of complex multi-window layout? Are you creating/presenting this alert in the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `UIWindow:0x7aebc600.height == 0`. I'm *guessing* that your issue.

Obviously your window height shouldn't be set to 0, otherwise whatever that you add to it won't have enough height.

Additionally you can find a very good debugging tutorial from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/DebuggingTricksandTips.html). On the page search for "Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint"